# Running Hotmail conversations oldest to newest (like Gmail)

Tags: outlook.com

Hotmail has Gmail-style conversations nowadays, but they're exactly backwards, in my personal opinion: they run newest to oldest, rather than oldest to newest. I can change the order of the thread list, but not the actual messages in the thread.

Am I missing something, or is that just the way things are?

Comment: Is this still an issue now that Hotmail has been subsumed by Outlook.com?